# switching view in another mode swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using `UITabbarcontroller` in my application to switching between `UIViewController`. But I need to add another method, the user's in addition can switch between views with a button (in the screen shot an arrow) that will take them in the next view.
This is an example: 
[Screen shot](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/3230/d3FkkA.png)

Comment: are the other view controllers children of an item of the tabbarcontroller? if so you should put the root controller in navigation controller then push other controller in it when requested.

Comment: can you show me an example? @HashmatKhalil

Comment: i think i saw a good tutorial here - > http://makeapppie.com/2014/09/09/swift-swift-using-tab-bar-controllers-in-swift/

Comment: and on opening a child controller you do: self.navigationController.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)

Comment: How to add a transition animation ? @HashmatKhalil

Comment: i think you should read this: http://objectivetoast.com/2014/03/17/custom-transitions-on-ios/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just resolve that this is the code:

```
self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0
```